# webpack fails to compile with some EJS tags in template

Tags: webpack, ejs

Webpack fails to compile when I use some EJS tags in template. Such as `<%#` and `-%>`.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'index.ejs'
}),
```

In `webpack.config.js` I use `html-webpack-plugin` without any additional options, as it says in documentation that with EJS I can use no loaders, EJS is default. And everything goes well until I use in template those tags that I mentioned above.

How can I tweak my `webpack.config.js` to use all the features of EJS? I've tried to use `ejs-loader` but it doesn't help.